# Oracle 11g : split CLOBs into rows using a native function?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, clob

I have column that lists CLOBs.

Each CLOB is of this form :

```
file1.ext1
file2.ext2
file3.ext3
```

What I want to do is to convert all CLOBS combined to rows listed without the use of a PL/SQL program. In other words, **is there a native function that will allow me to get the content of all CLOBs splitted into lines** ?

Comment: See 2nd answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647041/reading-clob-line-by-line-with-pl-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LISTAGG function in your select, something like:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(COL_a,',') 
  FROM MyTable
 WHERE ....
```

Note: I never checked how this would work with CLOBs, so...

Comment: `LISTAGG` requires `WITHIN`, and to use `WITHIN` I need to have a cell that will be transformed to a row. In my case, one cell (CLOB) contains many lines that should be converted to rows : 1 cell ==> many rows

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted your question. What you mean is to split each CLOB into rows? (for a single CLOB or all CLOBS combined?). If that is the case and within each CLOB there is an indication of where a line ends (say `|`), you can simply `SELECT (REPLACE(Col_a,'|',CHR(10))...` or something like this.

Comment: 1) a COLB contains many lines 2) I need all CLOBs combined to be splitted into rows 3) there is no indication where the line ends, there's just a back return (like in a text editor)

Comment: Wait a minute... If you create a small anonymous block in SQL-Developer that would select one CLOB value into a variable, and then print the variable on screen, you are getting the text already split into lines? (you wrote _there's just a back return (like in a text editor)_)

Comment: If the answer is YES, I strongly suggest to test my original `SELECT` within SQL-Developer (NOT USING SELECT BUT PRINTING THE RESULT).

Comment: Yes, either printing or selecting... What I need is to list those rows. But how ?

Comment: Could you please try the query I suggested in my answer? (you might need to use a `CHR(10)` instead of a `,` as the last parameter of `LISTAGG`).

Comment: As I told you before, `LISTAGG` requires `WITHIN` and I can't use it in my context.

Comment: OK. Don't understand why, but... Anyway, no more ideas for the time being.