# REGEX check only when start of line

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g

Suppose we want to keep the entire line of a string only if a particular word say e.g 'test' appears at starting of line.

If it appears anywhere then the entire line should be removed

e.g

```
if function_test()=5; //here this entire line should be removed

test sample =5; //here this entire should be there
```

Comment: There is no stored procedure as such.From whole source code I have to do the above stuff i.e remove that particular line where word test is coming anywhere apart from beginning

Comment: This is more of regex kind of thing

Comment: If there is no stored procedure then why did you tag it with PL/SQL?

Comment: Are these multiple rows in a table, or multiple lines in a varchar2/CLOB value or variable, or something else? i..e what are you removing the lines *from*? And what about lines that don't contain 'test' at all?

Comment: @Alex the lines that don't contain 'test' should be there.These are multiple lines of a source code of clob data type.These source code passes through a pl/sql block after passing the lines having test anywhere apart from beginning should be removed

Comment: Do the matching lines have to be completely removed (so line count of CLOB goes down), or can they just be replaced with empty lines?

Comment: @Alex They have to be removed completely.Yes the line count of CLOB goes down

Comment: Then I think you'll have to process the CLOB line by line and rebuild it with the lines that you want to keep, as Tamas suggested. Doing `regexp_replace(old_str, '^.+test.*$', null, 1, 0, 'm')` will blank them, but I don't know of a way to remove the line completely (in multiline mode, in Oracle).

Comment: @alex Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 10g R2 on you should be able to use the anchor `\A` to require the match at the beginning of the string (will only work for single-line strings thus).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/oracle.html

Comment: There are multiple lines of a source code of clob data type.These source code passes through a pl/sql block after passing the lines having the word 'test' anywhere apart from beginning should be removed.So input is source code and I have to write something in the pl/sql block so that this happens

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by keep / remove lines? Where is this regex supposed to run? I.e. is it a part of an SQL command, or part of a grep, or sg else?

Regarding SQL you can use [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) operator:

```
WHERE line LIKE 'test%'
```

You can use [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) too:

```
WHERE substring(line, 1, 4) = 'test'
```

Using grep or any other language, you can specify start of line, e.g.:

```
grep '^test' bigfile.txt
```

Comment: this regex will be written in pl/sql block which passes the whole source coden as input string and in that remove that particular line where word test is coming anywhere apart from beginning

Comment: @BeastLesnar then, the `LIKE` operator should do the job for you.
For case insensitive match you can use the `LOWER` function too: `LOWER(line) LIKE 'test%'`.

Comment: I did not get you completely.Could you please elaborate as I am new to this

Comment: @BeastLesnar please show the code you have - it  can be incomplete, no problem. Then I'll add this `LIKE` expression, that should clear up everything :)

Comment: There are multiple lines of a source code of clob data type.These source code passes through a pl/sql block after passing the lines having the word 'test' anywhere apart from beginning should be removed.So input is source code and I have to write something in the pl/sql block so that this happens

Comment: Then, first you need to read that text line by line. As explained at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647041/reading-clob-line-by-line-with-pl-sql) SO question.

Comment: Can't there be solution like this -: REGEXP_REPLACE (source_code,'^test.*', '',1,0,'m');  Here it searches for test in beginning if it  finds then removes that line.I want exact opposite if start then keep otherwise remove

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
...
WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(string,'^test','i') THEN
     //this is a good line, do what you want or return string;
END
...
```